# Getting multiple 404 and 405 errors in Teams Bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-application-insights, microsoft-teams

I'm doing some investigating around a Teams Bot that I currently have in development. I'm seeing a lot of 404, and in some other cases, 405 errors when I look in Application Insights - I'm trying to understand if I've missed anything.

[image]

I have the App Service set to 'Always On' so my assumption is that it's polling the service every 5 minutes to keep it from idling out. However, I'm seeing a lot of 404 failures, specifically pointing to the *GET/* endpoint and in other cases a 405 error as well, which is pointing to the *api/messages* endpoint.

I have the App ID and App Password set in the environment variables and I've set the storage using a Cosmos DB too as shown in the index.js file below. I have also checked the Teams manifest to ensure it's pointing to the Bot ID and recently added the bot domain as well to see if that makes a difference.

```
const restify = require('restify');
const path = require('path');

// Import required bot services.
// See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter, ConversationState, UserState } = require('botbuilder');

// Import required services for bot telemetry
const { ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient, TelemetryInitializerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder-applicationinsights');
const { TelemetryLoggerMiddleware, NullTelemetryClient } = require('botbuilder-core');

// Import our custom bot class that provides a turn handling function.
const { DialogBot } = require('./bots/dialogBot');
const { ProvisioningProfileDialog } = require('./dialogs/provisioningProfileDialog');

// Read environment variables from .env file
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

// Create the adapter. See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about using information from
// the .bot file when configuring your adapter.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

// Define the state store for your bot.
const { CosmosDbPartitionedStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');

const cosmosStorage = new CosmosDbPartitionedStorage({
    cosmosDbEndpoint: process.env.CosmosDbEndpoint,
    authKey: process.env.CosmosDbAuthKey,
    databaseId: process.env.CosmosDbDatabaseId,
    containerId: process.env.CosmosDbContainerId,
    compatibilityMode: false
});

// Create conversation state with storage provider.
const conversationState = new ConversationState(cosmosStorage);
const userState = new UserState(cosmosStorage);

// Create the main dialog.
const dialog = new ProvisioningProfileDialog(userState);
const bot = new DialogBot(conversationState, userState, dialog);
dialog.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;

// Catch-all for errors.
const onTurnErrorHandler = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    //       application insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${ error }`);

    // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in Bot Framework Emulator
    await context.sendTraceActivity(
        'OnTurnError Trace',
        `${ error }`,
        'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error',
        'TurnError'
    );

    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity('The bot encountered an error or bug.');
    await context.sendActivity('To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.');
    // Clear out state
    await conversationState.delete(context);
};

// Set the onTurnError for the singleton BotFrameworkAdapter.
adapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler;

// Add telemetry middleware to the adapter middleware pipeline
var telemetryClient = getTelemetryClient(process.env.InstrumentationKey);
var telemetryLoggerMiddleware = new TelemetryLoggerMiddleware(telemetryClient);
var initializerMiddleware = new TelemetryInitializerMiddleware(telemetryLoggerMiddleware);
adapter.use(initializerMiddleware);

// Creates a new TelemetryClient based on a instrumentation key
function getTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey) {
    if (instrumentationKey) {
        return new ApplicationInsightsTelemetryClient(instrumentationKey);
    }
    return new NullTelemetryClient();
}

// Create HTTP server.
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }.`);
    console.log('\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator');
    console.log('\nTo talk to your bot, open the emulator select "Open Bot"');
});

// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // Route the message to the bot's main handler.
        await bot.run(context);
    });
});
```

Whilst the Bot appears to run okay for the most part, am I missing something with these errors or is this expected behaviour since it's polling for a response?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please check if you have [availability tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability#create-a-url-ping-test) configured?

Answer (score 0):

1. Does your bot contain a web page as well? The node samples do not, but [.NET samples do](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/wwwroot). If not, it would make sense, of course, to receive a 404. I tend to agree with you that the polling might be the cause.
2. Bots typically (especially when created from template or sample), *do not* handle GET endpoints to /api/messages. Everything is handled using POST.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have a web page in my deployment (it is using Node). This might be a silly question, but could it be that my Teams Bot has been deployed as a Web App Bot? My understanding of Bot Channels is that they are used when Bots are hosted elsewhere and not in Azure?!

Comment: Channel is connection between the communication application and the bot. There are number standard set of channels provided in the list to choose from. For more details on Channels, please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).